# Download file from Javascript in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
$http.post("/Controller/Method", {
                variable: parameter,
                variable2: jsonObject,
                variable3: parameter3,
                variable4: parameter4
}).then(function (response) {
    var dlAnchorElem = document.getElementById('downloadAnchorElem2');
    var header = response.headers('Content-Disposition');
    var filename = header.split("filename=");
    if (filename[1].charAt(0) === '"' && filename[1].charAt(filename[1].length - 1) === '"') {
        filename[1] = filename[1].substr(1, filename[1].length - 2);
    }
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("href", response.data);
    dlAnchorElem.setAttribute("download", filename[1]);
    dlAnchorElem.click();
});
```

This works great, in Chrome.  Doesn't work in Firefox, Edge, or IE8.  Currently, I'm trying to solve for IE8, cause if that solution is compatible, I can just use that, if not, I can try Filesaver or one of the other cross-browser solutions I've seen that explicitly don't work for IE 8.

Comment: If I remember correctly IE8 does not support data uris (expect for in CSS)...

Comment: @epascarello [You are right on the money about that.](http://caniuse.com/#search=data%20uri)

Comment: @epascarello, yeah, but other than that one line(which was superfluous, so I deleted it) am I -using- URI?